# Special recognition for specialist badges?

Tags: feature-request, jobs

The specialist badges are suppose to indicate you are highly active in a particular area.

How about highlighting this fact in the career pages? Or maybe even update the flair box to show this off.

It is one thing for me to list a tag as something I like, but there is much more weight if the careers website shows that I earned it. I don't think many of the HR people on careers will be browsing through profiles to see what badges people earned.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe a solution might be this one :

- for each tags that are in the "likes" list of a user,
- if a tag corresponds to a specialist bagde on SO,
- do not display that tag, but, instead, display the badge.

For instance, considering I have the ["specialist" badge on SO for "php"](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/93/php), my CV could appear this way in the search results employer view :

[image]
<sub>(source: [pascal-martin.fr](http://extern.pascal-martin.fr/so/careers-specialist-tag-idea-1.png))</sub>

And, of course, the same could be done for the view CV page, and public view, I suppose...

Answer (score 2):

You *could* highlight it in your Personal Statement... maybe just add a list of badges at the end that you are proud of (there used to be some ways to [generate badge images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10299/for-those-that-demand-those-elusive-badges), but these appear broken now).

You could also try to do it in a sneaky way so that the employer doesn't even realize *you* put it there. Adding an image of the badge(s) to your Personal Statement (which I'm pretty sure you can do) would make it look like it's simply a part of the careers site:

> ### Specialist badges

[image: matlab silver badge]

Comment: I mentioned mine in my SO profile. If I were on Careers, I'd probably do the same.

Comment: I could highlight it in my personal statement, but I think having it as a feature of careers gives the statement more weight because I didn't put it there. The site recognized it.

Comment: I agree it would be a nice built-in feature, but you usually have to wait 6-8 weeks for those. ;)

Comment: I'm in no rush :)